# flex child column to be offset by 50% of siblings overall height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 columns where I would like the right column to be offset by 50% of the left columns overall height. However the overall height is dynamic for each item depending on the content. I've tried doing this a bunch of different ways, including `top: 50%`. I'm thinking the only way to do this could be with vanilla Javascript, getting the height of the `.col-main` and then applying a margin-top to `.col--alt`? But I'm wondering if I've possibly missed a CSS solution?

Image below showing what I'm trying to achieve, but the heights will be dynamic and not guaranteed to be 740px.

[image]

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bgp5Loz/1/) can be found here with a code example.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-6 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    display: block;
}

.col--alt {
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 col--main">
      <h2>
        this is a title and test
      </h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam mauris a massa dapibus efficitur. Donec scelerisque leo eget neque lacinia, id tincidunt est tempus. Nunc tincidunt sit amet diam in vestibulum. Phasellus ut sagittis leo. Fusce ut est convallis, commodo diam id, vehicula nulla. Fusce congue, nibh fringilla dignissim blandit, enim nunc mollis metus, finibus pharetra lectus elit eu libero. Nunc sodales ultricies placerat. Proin auctor consequat augue sed commodo.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 col--alt">
      <h2>
        another title and test
      </h2>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam mauris a massa dapibus efficitur. Donec scelerisque leo eget neque lacinia, id tincidunt est tempus. Nunc tincidunt sit amet diam in vestibulum. Phasellus ut sagittis leo. Fusce ut est convallis, commodo diam id, vehicula nulla. Fusce congue, nibh fringilla dignissim blandit, enim nunc mollis metus, finibus pharetra lectus elit eu libero. Nunc sodales ultricies placerat. Proin auctor consequat augue sed commodo.
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col--main">
      <h2>
        this is a title and test
      </h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam mauris a massa dapibus efficitur. Donec scelerisque leo eget neque lacinia, id tincidunt est tempus. Nunc tincidunt sit amet diam in vestibulum. Phasellus ut sagittis leo. Fusce ut est convallis, commodo diam id, vehicula nulla. Fusce congue, nibh fringilla dignissim blandit, enim nunc mollis metus, finibus pharetra lectus elit eu libero. Nunc sodales ultricies placerat. Proin auctor consequat augue sed commodo.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 col--alt">
      <h2>
        another title and test
      </h2>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam mauris a massa dapibus efficitur. Donec scelerisque leo eget neque lacinia, id tincidunt est tempus. Nunc tincidunt sit amet diam in vestibulum. Phasellus ut sagittis leo. Fusce ut est convallis, commodo diam id, vehicula nulla. Fusce congue, nibh fringilla dignissim blandit, enim nunc mollis metus, finibus pharetra lectus elit eu libero. Nunc sodales ultricies placerat. Proin auctor consequat augue sed commodo.
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col--main">
      <h2>
        this is a title and test
      </h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam mauris a massa dapibus efficitur. Donec scelerisque leo eget neque lacinia, id tincidunt est tempus. Nunc tincidunt sit amet diam in vestibulum. Phasellus ut sagittis leo. Fusce ut est convallis, commodo diam id, vehicula nulla. Fusce congue, nibh fringilla dignissim blandit, enim nunc mollis metus, finibus pharetra lectus elit eu libero. Nunc sodales ultricies placerat. Proin auctor consequat augue sed commodo.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 col--alt">
      <h2>
        another title and test
      </h2>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam mauris a massa dapibus efficitur. Donec scelerisque leo eget neque lacinia, id tincidunt est tempus. Nunc tincidunt sit amet diam in vestibulum. Phasellus ut sagittis leo. Fusce ut est convallis, commodo diam id, vehicula nulla. Fusce congue, nibh fringilla dignissim blandit, enim nunc mollis metus, finibus pharetra lectus elit eu libero. Nunc sodales ultricies placerat. Proin auctor consequat augue sed commodo.
      </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only possible pure CSS approach I can see would be to absolutely position the second column (`top:50%`, relative to the container height that the first column will span up) - but that of course would get you in trouble with any content following this. I'm not an expert in `grid` layouts, but I don't think that provides anything that could help accomplish this either - so you will probably have to use JS here.

Comment: what the logic behind this? you can easily end with overlapping issue if you want to apply the same thing to the bottom columns

Answer (score 0):

if you use a simple grid layout with auto-sized rows, the first row will try to calculate itself with half of the inside item's height.

the first col takes the 2 first rows `grid-row: 1 / 3;` and the second col takes the middle shred row and the 3rd-row `grid-row: 2 / -1;`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container>div {
  background: blue;
}

.col-1 {
  height: 200px;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.col-2 {
  height: 370px;
  grid-row: 2 / -1;
  grid-column: 2 /-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>

</div>
```